# Moving Ball in GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, applet

How can I make by pressing left and right buttons moving the ball?
Here is the code:

```
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton left;
    private JButton right;
    private Container c = getContentPane();

    cycle() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        right = new JButton("RIGHT");
        right.addActionListener(this);

        left = new JButton("LEFT");
        left.addActionListener(this);
        c.add(panel);
        panel.add(right);
        panel.add(left);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        cycle ball = new cycle();
        f.add(ball);
        f.setTitle("Move the ball");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(150, 50, 150, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) class.

In particular:
`KeyListener#keyPressed(KeyEvent e);` and `KeyListener#keyReleased(KeyEvent e);`

For example, while the left arrow key is pressed and not yet released, continue to move the ball left frame by frame.  When the key is then released, stop moving the ball.

The benefit you get by doing it this way is that you can handle multiple held keys at once while avoiding keyboard repeat rates differing from user to user.

Edit: my mistake, I thought by button you were referring to a key on your keyboard...

Instead of using `KeyListener`, you can use the [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) class.

If you'd like to achieve the same thing using JButtons, you can use `JButton#addMouseListener` and add a `new MouseAdapter()` to it.  You'll have to specify `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` just like the previous part of my answer regarding `KeyListeners`.

Here's an example:

```
public JButton aButton;

...
...

public void static main (String... args) {

    ...
    ...

    aButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            // Start doing stuff.  In your case, going left or right.
            // In this situation, it may be best to use a state variable like in the KeyListener example.
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            // Stop doing stuff.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I thought of that and Ι saw it here in another post but i am trying to learn by buttons.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, by buttons I thought you meant keys for some reason.  I've fixed the original answer, it should be more accurate now.

Comment: That is I wanted to hear, by aButton.addMouseListener. But the problem is how can work with going left or right. I think is: if left then x+1 and right x-1

Comment: Do you have a frame rate system working already?  I'm assuming you're making some sort of game.

If you don't have a way to control when the view is repainted, we will have to deal with that first before being able to move the ball.

Comment: *"i am trying to learn by buttons"* This question is very confusing. 1) By 'buttons' DYM a `JButton` or mouse buttons? 2) Why did the title say 'applet' when the code is using a `JFrame`?

Comment: Cause I am a beginner.